# 3 conditions in an Excel if(and) formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help combining 3 conditions into an Excel if(and) formula ie.

If printer = ABC and Cartridge = A1000 and Paper = Gloss then price = 100

(and then obviously the cartridge could be A2000 for a different colour or Paper could be Matt)

I've tried

`=IF(AND(C10="ABC",C16="A1000",C24="Gloss"),100,
IF(AND(C10="ABC",C16="A1000",C24="Matt"),90,
IF(AND(C10="ABC",C16="A2000",C24="Gloss"),110,0)))`  for example

The user will select the printer, and cartridge and paper from drop down list filters.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is this not working?  You're proposed formula looks fine to me.  If you need help debugging, I usually break up the formula into three cells to see the results of each subsequent if statement.  Perhaps you can tell us what you expect to happen and what you see happening that is wrong.  It's not quite clear to me at least.

Comment: The formula gets quite long as there are 3 printers and 2 cartridge options each, and you can print on gloss or matt for each printer and cartridge. Do you know if there a limit to the number of if(and)s you can use in a formula? Otherwise I will have to split it out as suggested.

Comment: :)  I have personally had 20 if statements, but I broke them out into multiple columns, the max I've found is around 7-8...  So, no, I don't know of a limit (though, I'm sure one exists).  If you need to, though, break the formula into multiple columns to simplify this.

Comment: Would help to know what version of Excel you're using; there are some interseting ways of getting around this but they depend on version.

Comment: If the list becomes too long, VBa *may* be an option, it remains out the way and if set up well, should be easy to update. But, it is VBa and so can scare some people off

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cram a lot of combinations into one `IF` statement. There is a limit to how many you can nest, but it's normally bigger than anyone needs (I'd have thought 18 was fine.)

The real issue is that this way of doing it means you can’t change the prices or add options without changing the formula. Luckily the solution to this is easy.

First you'll need a lookup table:

1. Make a table somewhere with the following columns: Key, Printer, Cartridge, Paper and Price
2. In the Key column paste this formula: `=[@Printer]&[@Cartridge]&[@Paper]`*
3. Fill the table with all the combinations and prices
4. Name the table `PrintingOptionsLookups`
   [image: Table]

Next, where you would put your IF formula, instead use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(C10,C16,C24),PrintingOptionsLookups,5,FALSE)
```

This will roll up the selections into a single value and then look for a match in the Key column, then return the price. That way you can add products and change prices in the future without having to modify the formula.

*Tables and References like this require Excel 2007 and up

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SUMPRODUCT.  Like ClockeWork says, in Excel 2007 and up, you can use a table.  (SUMPRODUCT should work in earlier versions of excel.)  See http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/01/the-venerable-sumproduct.html  for a superb explanation of SUMPRODUCT.

Using CLockeWork's table with its column names, the formula would be

=SUMPRODUCT(PrintingOptionsLookups[Price]
            * (MyPrinter    =PrintingOptionsLookups[Printer])
            * (MyCartridge  =PrintingOptionsLookups[Cartridge])
            * (MyPaper      =PrintingOptionsLookups[Paper])
           )

See the graphic below.

[image]